# my else if statement isnt working in my tic tac toe program

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

//main code

public static void main(String[] args) {

//initiate game board

```
initGame();
    //start the game
    do {
        PlayerMove(Cplayer);
        updategame(Cplayer, crow, ccol);
        printboard();
        //game over message
        if (currentstate == you_win){
            System.out.println("'X' Won!!");
            else if (currentstate == comp_win)
                System.out.println("'O' won!!");
                else if (currentstate == draw)
                System.out.println("It's a Draw :(");
        }
```

Comment: Your curly braces are set in a way that doesn't mesh with your intended activity. if and else should be at the same level.

Comment: please better formatting ? `do { }` ?

Comment: What data type are `currentstate`, `you_win`, `draw` and `comp_win`?  They're not Strings are they?

Comment: Ooh, and ALWAYS use `{` `}` characters.   Otherwise, your intention is unclear, both to humans reading the code, and the compiler.

Comment: Please be more specific than "not working."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (currentstate == you_win){
        System.out.println("'X' Won!!");
        else if (currentstate == comp_win)
            System.out.println("'O' won!!");
            else if (currentstate == draw)
            System.out.println("It's a Draw :(");
    }
```

Take a look at this line (and I removed some extraneous code to make this easier to see):

```
    if (currentstate == you_win){
        else if (currentstate == comp_win)
            //...
    }
```

Looking at it this way, can you see why this is incorrect? Incidentally, this is why you should always use `{` and `}`. Do the `if`...`else` like this instead:

```
if (currentstate == you_win){
      // ...
 }
 else if (currentstate == comp_win) {
     // ...
  }
    //...
```

Or, even better, just use a `switch` statement:

```
switch (currentstate) {
       case you_win:
             System.out.println("'X' Won!!");
             break;
        case comp_win:
            System.out.println("'O' won!!");
            break;

        case draw:
            System.out.println("It's a Draw :(");
            break;
}
```

Comment: oh I see, thank you so much!